# Align musical sheet bar lines with table columns

Tags: tables, spacing, music, lilypond

This is kind of a very obscure question, but I'll try anyways. How do I typeset musical notes so that the bars separating them align with a table below? I've tried lilypond, and I've tried various spacing options provided, but can't get it to work. The notes always have slight variances in spacing, for example a note with a sharp before it takes a few pixels more space than one without it. I've also tried hand-ajusting and hard-coding the column widths, but can't get those to work either.

I'm not particularily bound to lilypond (I only need to typeset this particular line from the MWE) so any other package would also be fine with me.

In a perfect world I would like to set the distance between bars (e.g. 1cm), center the notes between the bars and attach the sign before the note. Then I can adjust the first column in the table for the key and leave the other columns at 10cm width.

It also apprears to me that sometimes the bars have different widths (like the 3rd bar in the screenshot). Is that a bug with lilypond or some setting I missed? The screenshot was taken at 100% zoom.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{ltjarticle}
\usepackage{lyluatex}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}
\begin{document}
    
    \begingroup
    \begin{lilypond}
        \new Staff {
            \set Score.proportionalNotationDuration = #(ly:make-moment 1)
            %\override Score.SpacingSpanner.strict-note-spacing = ##t
            \omit Staff.TimeSignature
            \relative c' { d1 dis1 es1 e1 f1 fis1 ges1 g1 gis1 as1 a1 ais1 bes b1 c1 cis1 des1 }
        }
    \end{lilypond}
    \endgroup%
    \begingroup
        \hspace{-0.23cm}
        \huge
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ |p{0.2cm}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering}|p{0.51cm}<{\centering}|p{0.51cm}<{\centering}|p{0.51cm}<{\centering}|p{0.51cm}<{\centering}|p{0.51cm}<{\centering}|p{0.51cm}<{\centering}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering}|p{0.54cm}<{\centering} }
        \hline
        \normalsize 1 & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\ 
        \hline
        \normalsize 2 & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\ 
        \hline
        \normalsize 3  & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ \\ 
        \hline
        \normalsize 4  & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ \\ 
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \endgroup
    
\end{document}
```

[image: How it looks]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to align the measures in the `lilypond` environment with the LaTeX table because I believe they can't take or pass information to each other. But the thing here is: what are you trying to make? Some kind o fingering chart? A woodwind diagram?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make a fingering chart.

Comment: Well, you didn't say what instrument you're trying to make a fingering chart, but Lilypond has several predefined woodwind diagrams. Check the documentation [here](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/notation/woodwind-diagrams).

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to make fingering diagrams for historic flutes with various amounts of keys. It looks like you can add custom diagrams so I'll check it out. I kind of managed to align the chart with the bars by hand, so if it doesn't work, I'll stick with what I have. Do you know if the build in charts offer different formats? I need three octaves and the example charts take a lot of space individually. Some flutes have up to four fingerings for a single note.

Comment: The documentation says that you can customize the diagrams, but you must certainly have some skill with the Scheme language. You can also try the solutions presented on an official mailing list topic [here](http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/Custom-woodwind-diagram-td207588.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution per se, but I have a way, that likely will work.

Start by creating a lilypond snippet in the desired width, see also my answer in [music.sx](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/76950/lilypond-with-latex). You need to edit the make moment value: 1/20 is denser than 1/40. Doubling the divisor is like "one step". Remove the bar engraver with `\remove "Bar_engraver"`:

```
  \context {
    \Score
    \remove "Bar_number_engraver"
    \remove "Bar_engraver"
    \override SpacingSpanner.base-shortest-duration = #(ly:make-moment 1/200)
  }
```

The snippets, you create with this lilypond setup, won't contain bars. If this doesn't work, put the command `\bar""` anywhere, where a bar is. It sets the bar to "invisible bar", which means, it is still there, but invisible. i.e. `c4 a8 a b2 \bar"" e4 e a4`

Once you have this, you need two boxes in LaTeX. The first one contains the staff, the second one contains the bars and they are laid over each other.

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{% parbox A; optional if vertical alignment doesn't work, like intended
\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=\linewdith]{yourSnippet.pdf}\hspace{-\linewidth}\hspace}%
\parbox[c][<height of your lilypond snippet>][c]{\linewidth}{%
\def\notebar{\rule{<width>}{<yourStaffHeight>}}
\hspace{<sizeOfFirstColumn>}\notebar\hfill\notebar\hfill ... \notebar\null
}% inner parbox
%} %parbox A
```

The `%` at lineend are always needed to not produce any unwanted spaces.

After that use the `p{<columnwidth>}` option for your first column to fit the width of the staff key at staff begin.